# conditional rendering of components don't work in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement

I want to conditionally render my component named Login and Menubar according to the isLogin state.

I want to render either the login page or the Menubar page according to the "isLogin" state. if isLogin is false then render the login page either render the menubar page.
I use the "Ternary" Operator for this.
Now the problem is that when I press the login button in the Login component, the gotoMenu function calls the Handler function which is in App.js and I passed this function as Props in the Login component. It revokes the Handler function, it also changes the isLogin state to true, and renders the Menubar page for a second, and then again Login Page appears. I can't figure out what happened.

here is App.js Code

```
import React from 'react'
import Navbar from './components/Navbar';
import Menubar from './components/Menubar';
import Login from './components/Login';
import {
  useState
} from 'react';

const App = () => {
  const [isLogin, setisLogin] = useState(false);
  const Handler = () => {
    console.log("In app");
    setisLogin(true);
  }


  return ( 
    <>
       <Navbar /> 
       {!isLogin 
         ? <Login Handler = {Handler} /> 
         : <Menubar/ >
       }
    </>
  );
}
export default App
```

Button code in Login component

```
<button onClick={goTOMenu} className='font-mono  text-white text-4xl text-center'>Login</button>
```

Login component's gotoMenu function code :-

```
const Login = ({ Handler }) => {
  const goTOMenu = () => {
    console.log("switching");
    Handler();
  };
};
```

Comment: Try  const Handler = ()=> setisLogin(true);
Or const Handler = ()=>{
console.log("In app");
Return setisLogin(true);
}

Comment: Perhaps in your case using {} with arrow function down not return your setisLogin(true)

Comment: I do not think "Login" can appear again in your current code sample, could you provide a reproducible code snippet? By "Login appear again " I suppose your "App" component remount somehow, but your code snippet do not include such code

Comment: yaa, I think the App component remounts again but I don't understand how it happened.

Answer (score 0):

You are expecting that if the `isLogin` is `false` then it should return Login page,

> if isLogin is false then render the login page either render the
> menubar page.

Try to change the condition according to your requirement like this,

```
return ( 
    <>
       <Navbar /> 
       {isLogin 
         ? <Menubar /> 
         : <Login Handler = {Handler} />
       }
    </>
);
```

Comment: Yes, But the same logic is in My code also.

Answer (score 0):

Just tried to recreate your code on CodeSandbox, you can find it [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-bash-bfbjif?file=/src/App.js)

The behavior is as expected- clicking the login function invokes the goTOMenu function (as shown 'switching' being logged in the console), followed by the Handler function you are passing down as a prop (as shown by the 'In app' being console logged).

You can see that once Login is clicked, the Menubar gets rendered, and not the Login page.

Not sure if I'm missing something else here, do check and let me know. Happy to help.

Comment: Ohh ! Sorry the code that I mentioned here is absolutely right and works as expected. but actually, in my code, the button element which I mentioned here is wrapped in an anchor attribute and that is the reason, why my app component gets remounted. Thank you for your help..